# Function of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lebesgue-measure

Let $U$ be the set of all nonempty subsets of $[0,1]$ that are a union of finitely many  closed intervals (where an "interval" that is a single point does not count as an interval). Does there exist a function $f:U\times U\rightarrow U$ such that for any $A,B\in U$:

(a) $f(A,B) = f(B,A)$

(b) $f(A,B)$ has length (i.e. Lebesgue measure) less than $0.0001$.

(c) $f(A,B)\cap A$ has positive length.

(d)  The length of $f(X,B)\cap A$ is maximized at $X=A$.

This is a variant of this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312603/function-of-two-sets-intersection) with more restrictive conditions, so my guess would be that the answer is no.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: See the comments in the linked question

Comment: In d, it is not a requirement that $A$ is a unique maximizer. (from OPs comment in the linked question)

Comment: @pi66 Would you prefer to say $|f(A,B)\cap A| > 0$ (where $|\cdot|$ is Lebesgue measure) instead of $f(A,B)\cap A \not = \emptyset$ (the difference between the two is when $f(A,B)\cap A$ is a single point)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Despite the high bounty no answer yet. Still, a very interesting question that seems just a little too hard to prove. I'll keep on thinking.

Comment: Because the bounty is now over, I have started an "answer" with my results so far. I hope it helps the next person who thinks about this problem.

Comment: @Paul The question also attracted some answers which are now deleted. The most promising of them that I have seen claimed that they found such a function $f$. It would have been interesting to know where it went wrong (I am assuming that the function turned out to be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This is not actually an answer, only a place to share some
preliminary observations in the hopes that it will be useful for others.

**Idea for simplifying notation/proofs**:

Instead of using closed intervals in the question, one could
use only half-open intervals (for example, of the form $[a,b)\subset [0,1)$).
The problem statements should be equivalent with closed intervals or half-open
intervals.
The formulation with half-open intervals has the advantage that
one does not have to deal with closed "intervals" which consist of a single point.

Moreover, this would have the advantage that
$U_0:=U\cup\{\emptyset\}$ is stable with respect to intersections, unions, complements,
i.e.
$$
A\cap B, A\cup B, [0,1)\setminus A \in U_0 = U\cup\{\emptyset\}
\qquad
\forall A,B\in U_0 = U\cup\{\emptyset\}
$$
holds.

**Some consequences of (a)-(d)**:

Here, $|\cdot|$ refers to the Lebesgue measure
and we use the version with half-open intervals outlined above,
(but this can easily translated to the version with closed intervals).

The following should hold for all $A,B\in U$.
For now, I have not included details proofs.

(e) The length of $f(X,Y)\cap A$ is maximized at $(X,Y)=(A,A)$.

(f) We have $C\subset f(C,C)$, where $C=f(A,B)$.

(g) We have $C\subset f(C,B)$, where $C=f(A,B)$.

(h) We have $|f(A,B)|\leq \alpha := |f([0,1),[0,1))|$.
And also $\alpha\leq 0.0001$.

(i) We have $D_1 = f(D_1,D_1)$, where $D_1:=f([0,1),[0,1))$.

(j) We have $D_1 = f(D_1,[0,1))$, where $D_1:=f([0,1),[0,1))$.

**some remarks on the new conditions**:

(h) allows us to forget about $0.0001$, we just have to keep in mind that $\alpha$
is small.

It would be interesting to know if $f(C,C)=C$ can be shown for $C=f(A,B)$.
In the comments on MO it was first claimed that this is true, but then the user
said he does not remember the argument and does no longer make the claim.
I think one can maybe show something similar if we add intersections in the right places.